# how to get count of videos in a web page using code(by parsing it)

Tags: c#, asp.net, count

Does any one know how to check if the webpage has any videos or video links.

Like for example:

I am doing web automation for LG. Then i need all the video links(or `Counts of video` in a particular page).

This LG product link for product:[GR-D907SL](http://www.lg.com/au/fridges/lg-GR-D907SL) contains 12 Images, 1 Video and 0 Flash.

I am getting count for Images and flash. but how to get for videos?

Is there any way i can find there is a video?

Comment: Has any one got any thing on this question. please help

Answer (score 0):

I didnt find an answer for this so i did it using regular expresions
i identified using the

> keywords like EMBEDDED, PLAYER

if there is any answer please let me know